# Unable to update values in a column based on pattern match of another column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which has two columns Machine Name(character) and Region(factor).They have values as follows(few examples):

```
Machine Name Region
1233.corp.pdo.om APAC
xyz.om Europe
345.corp.pdo.cm Europe
abc12.cm Americas
```

So i want to update the region with pdo for the machines which have `corp.pdo` in them.But when i am trying to update its not happening using if else.Can you please help.